# How to create Angular 9 project with IVY?

Tags: project, angular9, angular-ivy

How to create Angular 9 project with IVY?

I tried the following:

```
ng new sample9prjivy --enable-ivy
```

**My environment:**

Angular CLI: 9.0.2

Node: 12.16.0

OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

**Package and Version**

@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.2

@angular-devkit/core         9.0.2

@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.2

@schematics/angular          9.0.2

@schematics/update           0.900.2

rxjs                         6.5.3

C:\src\Angular\pilot\A9>ng new sample9prjivy --enable-ivy

Unknown option: '--enable-ivy'

What I missed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable Ivy for Angular 8 or 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522756/how-do-i-enable-ivy-for-angular-8-or-9)

Comment: That tag should be `angular-ivy`, right? Not `ivy`.

Comment: As I saw no. I ran : npm i -g @angular/cli@next the result is the Angular version is 9.1.0-next.0 but the result is the same.

Comment: May I ask you how do you mean "angular-ivy"?

Comment: The question currently has three tags: `project`, `ivy`, and `angular9`.  If you hover your mouse over the `ivy` tag, you will see a description which refers to a Java/Ant-related tool - nothing to do with Angular.  There is a separate tag `angular-ivy` which specifically relates to an Angular compilation pipeline. I assume you want `angular-ivy` not `ivy`. The `ivy` tag brought me here :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. As an earlier poster tried to explain, there's no such "ng new" flag as `--enable-ivy`.
2. As  andrewjames explained above, the "ivy" tag is incorrect.  You want "angular-ivy".  I fixed it for you.
3. If you want to enable Ivy for older Angular builds, read this thread:  [How do I enable Ivy for Angular 8 or 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522756/).  You'll need to edit `tsconfig.json` and `angular.json`.
4. It looks like Ivy is now the default for Angular 9:

> https://angular.io/guide/ivy
>
> Ivy is the code name for Angular's [next-generation compilation and
>   rendering
>   pipeline](https://blog.angular.io/a-plan-for-version-8-0-and-ivy-b3318dfc19f7).
>   With the version 9 release of Angular, the new compiler and runtime
>   instructions are used by default instead of the older compiler and
>   runtime, known as View Engine.

5. As the documentation discusses, there *IS* a flag for `enableIvy` ... but it's set in `tsconfig.app.json`.   It is *NOT* a command line option for "ng new".

---

**Update:**

The answer to the OP's original question: you don't have to "create an Angular 9 project with Ivy": in Angular 9, Ivy should be enabled by default.

To answer the follow-on question about NG6002: look here (already cited below):

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35399
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35191

One final suggestion: it couldn't hurt to:

1. Update Angular: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`
2. Create a brand new project and copy the old source into the new project

---

**Another Update**

1. Original problem: `ng new sample9prjivy --enable-ivy` =>

> Unknown option: '--enable-ivy'

Cause: `--enable-ivy` simply isn't a legal "ng" option with Angular 9.  Don't do it!

2. Next problem: `I always got more error NG6002`

   This is a well-known issue upgrading existing projects to Angular 9.  Look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35399) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35191).  The basic issue is that "upgrading" the project can result in "inconsistencies".  Both links suggest workarounds; I've also suggested some workarounds.  I don't know if you've tried any of them yet :(
3. CURRENT SUGGESTION:

   Since you don't seem to be making much progress, I'd suggest the following:

   a) *UNINSTALL* Angular: get a "clean version":

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   npm cache clean
   npm cache verify
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```

   b) Confirm your "clean install" of Angular 9:

   ```
   ng --version
   ...
   Angular CLI: 9.0.3
   Node: 10.15.1
   OS: win32 x64

   Angular:
   ...
   Ivy Workspace:

   Package                      Version
   ------------------------------------------------------
   @angular-devkit/architect    0.900.3
   @angular-devkit/core         9.0.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.3
   @schematics/angular          9.0.3
   @schematics/update           0.900.3
   rxjs                         6.5.3
   ```

   c) Create a brand new project with your "known good" Angular install.

   Do *NOT* change *ANY* configuration!  Do *NOT* try to explicitly "enable Ivy"!

   d) Copy over your old source code (*ONLY* the project source code!) to your new project.

   e) Verify that "everything works".

   f) Post back what you find.

Comment: I follow step by step the guide how to enable IVY for old angular application, but I always got error NG6002

Comment: 1) Since you're on Angular 9, you *DON'T* want to follow any steps that *AREN'T* for Angular 9.  2) Look here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35399. Per the link: 3) `npm cache clean --force`.  4) `delete the top node_modules in the workspace (where you should have installed it), and rebuild libraries/apps.`.  See also: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35191

Comment: Iknow, but before A9 my prj was on A8. Now on A9, no errors, but I switched on enableIvy and allowEmptyCodegenFiles I always got more error NG6002. Where can I found the description and cause of error NG6002? Thanks

Comment: Sigh...  You shouldn't have to "switch on" anything :(  At least not if you start off with a brand new Angular 9 project.  Regarding NG6002, look at my links.  The issue seems to be "conflicts".  An ideal solution is to "start clean".  See my updates above.

Comment: Originally I started to update my A8 project to A9. After it I switched on enableIvy and allowEmptyCodegenFiles I always got more error NG6002. When I always got the mentioned error came to my mind, if I create a new A9 project with IVY and move my old project content, it can be good also, this inspire my the how can I create new A9 project with IVY usage.

Comment: Please 1) Read the links I cited, 2) Look at my updates, 3) Re-start your project from a "clean" install of Angular 9 and a "clean" Angular 9 project.