# ERROR in Symbol ClarityModule declared in ... clr-angular.module.d.ts is not exported from @clr/angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

When running `ng build` for my Clarity Design based application I get the following error (this is all the output):

`ERROR in Symbol ClarityModule declared in /Users/moo/code/test3/node_modules/@clr/angular/clr-angular.module.d.ts is not exported from @clr/angular (import into /Users/moo/code/test3/projects/demoapp/src/app/ui/ui.module.ts)`

- The application is building correctly on an older checkout of the same codebase, so I am quite sure this is related to the versions of (peer) dependencies like Angular, Clarity Design System or Node
- The application is using a library that also imports Clarity Module

I am trying to specifically pinpoint why and where Angular thinks `ClarityModule` is exported to get down what is causing this error and why it does not happen on another development deployment.

How can I get further information on this build error and fix it? This is the only line outputted by `ng build` so I am hoping to find some instructions on how to make it more verbose, or even a potential fix.

Angular is

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 12.16.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.7
@schematics/angular                9.0.7
@schematics/update                 0.900.7
ng-packagr                         9.0.3
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.2
```

Comment: What version of Clarity are you using? Only Clarity v3 will work with with Angular 9.

Comment: `@clr/angular@3.0.1`

Comment: This generally refers to something not compiling correctly with Ivy, which can happen if you're updating libraries or something manually. Try clearing node_modules and reinstalling with `npm ci`.

Comment: Have you updated to latest Claraity v3?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I have not tried the latest Clarity version yet, but will report the result when I get there. My first goal was to get the current version up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve this issue - how to find out what trips the error in the source code.

However as per the comment, the build works if you disable Ivy compiler

- Set `aot: false` in `angular.json` of the main app
- Set `enableIvy: false` in `tsconfig.json` of the main app

More information about Ivy compiler options here: [How do I enable Ivy for Angular 8 or 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522756/how-do-i-enable-ivy-for-angular-8-or-9)